# Rails: Exceptions vs conditional statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application that queries a 3rd party web service. I am trying to decide how to handle an invalid response (e.g. service unavailable).

The two options I am considering are:

1) WebService returns nil on error

```
response = WebService.query
if response
  # Query was successful
else
  # Invalid response
end
```

2) WebService raises an exception on error

```
begin
  response = WebService.query
rescue
  # Invalid response
end
# Query was successful
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? Which one is "the Rails way"?

Many thanks.

Comment: Considering it's 3rd party, it probably defines what the service returns, nil or raises exception on error. Or maybe both and each has it's own different meaning.

Comment: @shoebox639 is right, you must check which approach the 3rd party lib follows, and stick with it... If you're trying to decide how YOU will report errors to the rest of your code, then it's a different question.

Comment: Just to clarify, I know how the web service returns errors. My question is about deciding between the two approaches outlined to report errors to the rest of my code.

Comment: Ok, but the way you wrote the example doesn't make that clear. The top implies that the query returns either true or false or something else that can you test for success and failure. Whereas the bottom implies that the query raises and exception and you need to handle it. Perhaps WebService class is your wrapper for the 3rd party service.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Yes, WebService is my wrapper class, so I have the option of returning true/false or raising an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional statements are usually faster than exceptions. See [How slow are (Ruby) Exceptions?](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/01/how-slow-are-ruby-exceptions/)

The point is that Exceptions and conditional statements have different meaning. You use exceptions when you don't expect something to fail and when an error occurs is an exceptional event. On the opposite, conditional statements control a flow. This is the same concept expressed in [this post from Thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807850/save-bang-your-head-active-record-will-drive-you-mad).